# ruby regex test for exact match of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regex to exactly match if a string is a mongo id, not if a string contains a mongo id.  My regex for a mongo id is

```
/[a-z,0-9]{24}/
```

which works great, but I can't figure out how to write a regex that rejects a URL that contains a mongo id, for example.  So, I get this, which is not what I want:

```
pattern = /[a-z,0-9]{24}/
str1 = "589ab375c3c6416310171b5b"
str2 = "http://somewhere.com/589ab375c3c6416310171b5b?review"
str1.match pattern
```

output:

```
#<MatchData "589ab375c3c6416310171b5b">
```

And the second string

```
str2.match pattern
```

output:

```
#<MatchData "589ab375c3c6416310171b5b">
```

I want the first to match but the second to not.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Comment: Side note, if you don’t actually need the match data but just a boolean about whether the reflex matches or not, use `match?`. It’s more efficient as it doesn’t make a MatchData object or build backrefs ($1, $2, $3, etc).

Answer (score 2):

For your example data your could use [anchors](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) `\A` and `\z`. The data does not contain a comma so you can omit that from the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

For example:

`pattern = /\A[a-f0-9]{24}\z/`

[Demo](https://ideone.com/3ADRmZ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` and `$` to match exactly a whole string. `^` matches the start of a line, and `$` matches the end. So:

```
/^[a-z,0-9]{24}$/
```

will match a string containing only the 24 characters of a Mongo ID.

Comment: `\A` (start of string) and `\z` (end of string) are probably better anchors since yours will match `"http://somewhere.com/\n589ab375c3c6416310171b5b\n?review"`